# pug-php inline attribute condition

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements, pug, templating

I started using Pug recently and trying it out in a php environment.

I ran into an issue with inline conditions being applied to attributes.

What I am trying to do is something like the following:

```
$variable = 'red';  

div.class(
    if($variable):
        style="background-color:".$variable
    endif:
)
```

So what I need to happen is for the style attribute to not even show if the variable is empty or does not exist.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, I suggest setting the conditional in the actual attribute value:

`div.class(style=($variable ? "background-color:".$variable : undefined))`

I'm not sure whether this works in Pug PHP as it does in normal Pug, since I don't have a testing setup for that combination available. What I do know, however, is that Pug drops any attributes having `undefined` as value, meaning that the `style` attribute should only appear when `$variable` evaluates to a truthy value, which should correspond to the thing you're trying to achieve here.